# What is the best way to install PIL on Mac Snow Leopard with Xcode 4 installed?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

What is the best way to install PIL on Mac Snow Leopard with Xcode 4 installed? I have seen a lot of information about how difficult it is to install PIL on a Mac but nothing seems too definitive. is there any way to get it installed with the version of Python that comes with Snow Leopard or Xcode 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Install dependencies first**

**JPG**

Download http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz

```
tar xzf jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz 
cd jpeg*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Freetype**

from http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/

download http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/freetype/freetype2/2.4.4/freetype-2.4.4.tar.bz2

```
tar xjf freetype-2.4.4.tar.bz2
cd free*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**LittleCMS 1.19 NOT 2.0+**

NOT this ----http:// downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lcms/lcms/2.1/lcms2-2.1.tar.gz

Instead download http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lcms/lcms/1.19/lcms-1.19.tar.gz

```
tar xzf lcms-1.19.tar.gz
cd lcms*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Then install PIL**

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" sudo pip install PIL
```

(or preferably within a virtualenv)

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install PIL
```

Comment: Thank you. Still having trouble. I'm getting an error "building '_imaging' extension". I've tried pip and setup.py. I've tried 1.1.6 and 1.1.7. I'm wondering if I have setup residue that might be affecting matters? I've tried around 20 different methods based on all the other people having trouble installing PIL.

Comment: My problem seems due to 32/64 bit incompatibilities. I also have no idea how to properly uninstall the JPEG files since I've installed it quite a few times and a few different versions.

Comment: Great thank you.  I think a problem I was having is that I was using too old a version of the jpeg library (6b).  PIL lives!